# Froala Editor Plugins using React Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, froala

I am trying to add a custom plugin to a Froala Editor in my React app using the package `react-froala-wysiwyg`. I am following [this](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/concepts/custom/popup/) tutorial on how to add a custom popup/plugin. The problem I am having is that the app is written in typescript and a dependency of the package - `froala-editor` - is not definitely typed so I am having to make a custom type definition based on the one I found [here](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/2369).

Up until this point I have been able to add missing properties to the type definition as I go along but it gets more complicated when dealing with the functions that should be accessing the custom plugin. It goes like this ... I have a plugin called `smartFieldPlugin` which has three methods `initPopup`, `showPopup` and `hidePopup`. I've created a toolbar button to access the plugin as follows:

```
FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('smartFieldIcon', { NAME: 'Smart Field', template: 'text'})
FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('smartFieldButton', {
  title: 'Insert Smart Field',
  icon: 'smartFieldIcon',
  undo: true,
  focus: false,
  plugin: 'smartFieldPlugin',
  callback: function() {
    // this.smartFieldPlugin.showPopup();
    FroalaEditor.PLUGINS.smartFieldPlugin.showPopup();
    
  }
});
```

This throws the error: `property 'showPopup' does not exist on type '(editor: FroalaEditor) => CustomPlugin'`

For more context `CustomPlugin` and `PLUGINS` are defined in the type definition file as follows:

```
  export interface CustomPlugin {
    _init?(): void;
    showPopup?(): void;
    hidePopup?(): void;
  }

  export const PLUGINS: GenericObject<(editor: FroalaEditor) => CustomPlugin>;

  export type GenericObject<T = any> = { [key: string]: T };
```

I am wondering if anyone knows why I am seeing this error, a simple way around it, or a way to avoid typing issues in general with `react-froala-wysiwyg`. Thanks.

Comment: any progress on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `showPopup` lives in `CustomPlugin` instances, not in the function that generates them. The PLUGINS array maps plugin names to generator functions.